# How to add colours in Table Panel of grafana

Tags: grafana

I have created a table panel in Grafana as below:

[image: Table panel in Grafana]

My requirement is to make the status column to have corresponding color shown instead of having the value "Yellow", "Green"... i.e. the word "Orange" should represent the color as below:

[image: Colour to be shown instead of "Orange"]

Comment: could you please share the code or your dashboard json how you created the table panel? I am looking specifically show json data not time series metric?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can define thresholds which change the color of a value (options -> column styles). But you **can't** change the color of a line based on a string in it.

As a ugly workaround you could add an extra column with numbers. Like `1 (yellow)`, `2 (red)`, etc. and define a threshold for them. But thats still limited to **max 3**.

Comment: You can use `ARRAY_POSITION` to make this easy, e.g.: `select status, array_position(array['SUCCESS','FAILURE'], status) as state from mytable;`

Comment: @DoctorEval this would work on the database access layer but the question is about how to do it inside grafana. We don't even know which database the OP uses

Answer (score 4):

I just found the solution/workaround to this, since I was also looking for a solution. The solution is pretty similar to the first answer, but doesn't rely on an extra column (1,2,3).

**Limitation:** this only works for 3 rows, since we are going to use the threshold function which allows only 3 color values. (maybe by adding another rule you could use more colors..?)

*Here goes:*

1. In the "Queries" section of your table instead of text/strings give each row **a numeric Alias**
   eg. 1, 100 or 500 (choose values that are a bit apart, since these
   are the values the threshold is going to differentiate from).
2. Then switch to the "Visualisation" panel of the same table and create/change the rule for the column "Status" to "Type:
   Type=String" and in "Value mappings"--> "Type: Value to text".
3. Under "Value to text" you 'give back the text' to the values you defined earlier, e.g 1 = Yellow, 100 = Red, 500 = Green [..]
4. Now you can add the color to each row containing aString, by using the Threshold function:  "Thresholds=100,110" (if you chose 1,
   100 and 1000 before) "Color mode=row" "Colors:" (from lowest to
   highest) | Yellow | Red | Green.

And that should do it.